# Android Extract url with specific domain name from String

Tags: android, json

I am developing a JSON application. I am able to download all of the data but I'm running into an interesting issue. I am trying to grab a string with the domain name:

```
http://www.prindlepost.org/
```

When grabbing all of the JSON, I get an extremely large string which I am unable to paste in there. The part I am trying to parse out is:

```
<p>The road through Belgrade was quiet at 4 A.M. Besides the occasional whir of another car speeding by, my taxi was largely alone on the road. Through the windshield I could see the last traces of apartment blocks pass by as we left the outskirts of the city. Somewhere beyond the limits of my vision, I knew the airport waited, its converging neon runway lines already lighting up the pre-dawn darkness.</p>
    <div class="more-link-wrap wpb_button"> <a href="http://www.prindlepost.org/2015/06/this-is-a-self-portrait/" class="more-link">Read more</a></div>
```

where I am focusing on:

```
<a href="http://www.prindlepost.org/2015/06/this-is-a-self-portrait/" class="more-link">Read more</a></div>
```

I'm unfamiliar with extracting strings like this. In the end, I want to be able to save the URL as its own string. For example, the above  would be converted into:

```
String url = "http://www.prindlepost.org/2015/06/this-is-a-self-portrait/";
```

One thing to note, there are A LOT of URLs to narrowing down by class name may help me a bunch.

My initial guess was:

```
// <READ MORE>
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
String urlTemp = null;
if (m.find()) {
      urlTemp = m.group(1); // this variable should contain the link URL
}
Log.d("LINK WITHIN TEXT", ""+urlTemp);
// </READ MORE>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Blackbelt Please explain how this might answer my question. I tried the only answer on that question which was remotely possible for this problem type and it isn't supported by Android Java API. Everything else was either poorly written or "I don't know if this works in Android but just google html parser"

Answer (score 0):

It may be work trying to use something like: http://jsoup.org/

If you check out their example for parsing out links:

```
String html = "<p>The road through Belgrade was quiet at 4 A.M. Besides the occasional whir of another car speeding by, my taxi was largely alone on the road. Through the windshield I could see the last traces of apartment blocks pass by as we left the outskirts of the city. Somewhere beyond the limits of my vision, I knew the airport waited, its converging neon runway lines already lighting up the pre-dawn darkness.</p>"
            + "<div class=\"more-link-wrap wpb_button\">"
            + "<a href=\"http://www.prindlepost.org/2015/06/this-is-a-self-portrait/\" class=\"more-link\">"
            + "Read more</a></div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String relHref = link.attr("href"); // == "/2015/06/this-is-a-self-portrait/"
String absHref = link.attr("abs:href"); // "http://www.prindlepost.org/2015/06/this-is-a-self-portrait/"
```

Comment: Very thorough answer. I will have to wait until I get home from work later today to test this but the logic looks great.